# Is this a good way to start a anonymous task and continue with ui thread?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5.2

there have been some time since i worked with tasks and lambda expressions. Is this a good way to run a anonymous task with a lambda expression and then run code on the UI thread when task is finished?

```
private void btn_mods_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = false;
    Loading();
    Task task = new Task(() => {
        if (IsServiceIsUp() != false)
        {
            webServiceMods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_webServiceResponse).mods;
            webServiceBaseUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_webServiceResponse).basePath;
            Console.Write(webServiceBaseUrl);

        }
    });
    task.Start();
    task.ContinueWith((foo) =>
    {
        FinishedLoading();
        function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = true;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}

private void Loading()
{
    img_loading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void FinishedLoading()
{
    img_loading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

I tried to chain the task.Start directly but that gave me an error `Cannot Implicitly convert type void to System.Threading.Tasks.Task`.

Basically what i wanted to do was to chain the whole process from start to end.

```
Task task = new Task(() => {
    if (IsServiceIsUp() != false)
    {
        webServiceMods = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_webServiceResponse).mods;
        webServiceBaseUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_webServiceResponse).basePath;
        Console.Write(webServiceBaseUrl);

    }
}).Start();
```

In PHP I would do something like this:

```
$task = new Task(() => {
    if (IsServiceIsUp() != false)
    {
        $webServiceMods = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject($_webServiceResponse).mods;
        $webServiceBaseUrl = JsonConvert::DeserializeObject($_webServiceResponse).basePath;
        Console::Write($webServiceBaseUrl);

    }
})
->Start()
->ContinueWith(($foo) =>
{
    FinishedLoading();
    $function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = true;
}, TaskScheduler::FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Is this possible? If so, is there any reason to not do it, and if there is a better way to do this, could you give me an example?

And thanks!

Comment: I would use *async/await*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this rather easily and a bit cleaner with `async-await`:

```
private async void btn_mods_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsServiceIsUp())
        return;

    function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = false;
    Loading();
    await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(_webServiceResponse);
        Console.Write(result.webServiceBaseUrl);
    });

    FinishedLoading();
    function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Performance wise, I wouldn't be so sure you'd need to use a threadpool thread just for deserializing a JSON. I would definitely test this code to determine if it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks! Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your event handler as async function, then you don't have to start the task, it already runs asynchronously.

> All async functions should return Task instead of void and Task`<TResult`> instead of TResult. The only exception is the event handler. The event handler returns void

In proper async-await this would be as follows:

```
private async void btn_mods_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = false;
    Loading();
    if (IsServiceIsUp())
    {   // The service is up, start the deserialization
        // because this function is async, you can call other async functions
        // without having to start a task
        // The UI remains responsive
        webServiceMods = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(_webServiceResponse).mods;
        // because of the await above, the second task is started after the first is finished:
        webServiceBaseUrl = await JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(_webServiceResponse).basePath;
        // because of the await the second task is also finished            
        Console.Write(webServiceBaseUrl);
        FinishedLoading();
        function_buttons_stackpanel.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

> By making your event handler async your code will make full usage of async-await. Your code would look much neater without the magic of continueWith and other Task related functions from before the async-await era.

One final remark: the following code looks silly and unnecessary difficult:

```
if (IsServiceIsUp() != false) ...
```

This should of course be:

```
if (IsServiceIsUp()) ...
```